# Send a file on a samba share from python script

Tags: python, samba

I've a samba share on my NAS, which is accessible in R/W as guest.

From a python script on my raspberry, I would like to send some file.

I've made the following script:

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile('/home/pi/Test/README.md', r'\\192.168.0.30\Public\test')
```

I've no errors, but the file is not send to my NAS.

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you see the `\\192.168.0.30\Public` directory? can you create files manually in it? I'm surprised that you get no errors. Are you running that from the console? exceptions are thrown from `copyfile`, there are no silent errors.

Comment: Yes, from my windows computer, I connect to `\\192.168.0.30\Public` as guest and I'm able to write new files without any issue manually. I'm as surprised are you are. I'm running this with a simple `python testCopy.py`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Also to mention, I initially tried to copy to `//192.168.0.30/Public/test` and then I was having an error.

Comment: an error ? which error? you could try to change the destination to see how it behaves. like 1) invalid IP address, 2) invalid directory. Is `test` a directory BTW?

Comment: UNC paths are not a thing on Linux. You can't do this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `No such file or directory: '//192.168.0.30/Public/test`. And yes, `test` is a folder

Comment: @AndrewMedico Are you sure? I found here some guy saying that he was using UNC path and it was working. How should I do then if not with UNC path?

Comment: you could try `copy('/home/pi/Test/README.md', r'\\192.168.0.30\Public\test')` not copyfile.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre same things, no errors, but nothing has been copied. Also tried `copy2`

Comment: you could try `f = open(r'\\192.168.0.30\Public\test'\foo.txt'); f.write("HELLO"); f.close()` and see what happens.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Same thing

Answer (score 1):

I ended by creating a network share:

```
import subprocess

remoteHost="192.168.0.30"
remoteShare="Public"
remoteSubFolder="test"
remoteUser='picam'
remotePassword='picam'
localMountPoint = '/mnt/remoteServer'
destinationFolder = localMountPoint+'/'+remoteSubFolder

if not os.path.exists(localMountPoint):
    os.makedirs(localMountPoint)
command = "sudo mount -t cifs -o username="+remoteUser+",password="+remotePassword+" //"+remoteHost+"/"+remoteShare+" "+localMountPoint
logMsg("Executing mounting command: "+command)
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

And now the copy work. Not really what I was hopping but at least it works.